# How do I get Geolocation watchPosition to run until I get an accurate result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I've been using the Geolocation `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` but found that it's not as accurate as `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`. So my idea is to let run `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` until it gets an accuracy of `<=100` and then show the position, or an error if it fails within 15 seconds.

Here's what I got:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var geo_options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 15000,
            maximumAge: 0
        };
        var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
            showPosition,
            showError,
            geo_options
        );
    } else {
        // Error here. Geolocation disabled.
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    if (position.coords.accuracy > 100) {
        // Keep trying
    } else {
        // Fire up the map, we got a position!
        // Clear the watchID.
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
    }
}
```

My problem here is that I can't clear the watchID on success for some reason because it says it's undefined. I guess that's because the function is outside.

Is there an easy way to do this so that `showPosition` is only fired when the accuracy is below 100? Right now `showPosition` is fired at any time because it's inside the `watchPosition` function.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `watchID` **is** `undefined`. You've defined it within the scope of `getLocation` which does not share its scope with `showPosition`. Try declaring it outside of both of them.

```
var watchID;

function getLocation() {
  ...
  watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition, showError, geo_options);
}

function showPosition(position) {
  if (position.coords.accuracy <= 100) {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
  }
}
```

Pro-tip: if your code was running in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) it would have alerted you to this error.

```js
'use strict';

function declareX() {
  var x = 1;
}

function useX() {
  console.log(x);
}

declareX();
useX();
```